# Insert coding query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need to auto insert the next `orders_id` into an `Orders` table in a database. `orders_id` is not the primary Key, and it does not auto-increment

I need to query the database, find the last (highest) id value, increment 1, and insert it in Orders table in database. Actually, I have a shipping action which will provide address of shipping of orders. So as soon as the user fills address form and move to payments page, I want to simultaneously fill my `Orders` table by `max(orders_id)+1`.

I have built relations between `Address` table and `Orders` table but my `orders` Table is not getting populated. Please detail me correct codes to implement it in my controller in Yii.

My controller for shipping action goes like this:

```
public function actionCheckout_shipping()
    {
            $address_id = Yii::app()->session->get('address_id');
            if(!empty($address_id))
                $address = Address::model()->findByPk($address_id);
            else
                $address = new Address;

             $orders=new Orders;
             $orders_id = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT MAX('orders_id') FROM orders_temp")->queryScalar();
             $orders->orders_id=$orders_id+1;
             $orders->customer_id = 1;
             $orders->billing_address_id = Address::model()->address_id;
             $orders->shipping_address_id = Address::model()->address_id;
             $orders->payment_details_id = 1;
             $orders->order_date = date('d-m-y');
             $orders->shipping_amount= NULL;
             $orders->total_amount = 100;
             $orders->created_date = date('d-m-y');
             $orders->save();

            $this->render('checkout_shipping', array('address'=>$address,'selected_address'=>$selected_address),false,true);
```

I have inserted the code for ORDERS table to fill it after a user completes the filling of shipping address form.

ok,I have used the relations in my ORDERS model like this:

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'billingAddress' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Address', 'billing_address_id'),
            'shippingAddress' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Address', 'shipping_address_id'),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in your controller .

```
//$address_id = Yii::app()->session->get('address_id');// Temporary I set
$address_id = 1; // Remove this

        if(!empty($address_id))
    {
           $address = Address::model()->findByPk($address_id);
    }
        else
    {
        echo "error address id should be there";                
    }

  $order_id = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT MAX(orders_id) FROM orders")->queryScalar();
 $order_id = ($order_id)?($order_id+1):1;
      $orders=new OrdersTemp;
 $orders->orders_id = $order_id;
 $orders->customer_id = 1;
     $orders->billing_address_id = $address_id;
     $orders->shipping_address_id = $address_id;
     $orders->payment_details_id = 1;
     $orders->order_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
     $orders->shipping_amount= '44';
     $orders->total_amount = '10';
 $orders->shipping_address_id = 1;           
     $orders->created_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
 $orders->modified_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
     $orders->save();
 echo $address->address_id;
 echo "<br />";
 echo $address->addressOrders->orders_id;
 echo "<br />";             
 echo $address->addressOrders->total_amount;
     $this->render('checkout_shipping', array('address'=>$address),false,true);
```

Replace this function into CartController n check echoes in view file 
like echo $address->addressOrders->orders_id;  etc.

Change in model "OrdersTemp" is

```
    public function tableName()
{
    return 'orders';
}
```

Basic errors were there like table name you use 
 1. orders_temp and table name is "orders"
 2. Don't insert NULL as you set NOT NULL in Table structure.
 3. You didn't get values in order table b cause there was no values inserting into table.

Hope you find this useful

Comment: I couldn't get ur point clearly.Please explain the relations array and where sholud i put these codes...do we need to do the sql stuff in model or in controller???

Comment: Can you share your controller code So I can explain you here. OR I can correct your code. Also let me know your Address model relation array of orders.

Comment: I have shared my controller.Please rectify it wherever possible.Thanks

Comment: Point third:Then how could my database table ORDERS be populated if I dont give it values??

Comment: point One:I have defined address_id as primary key,not null in mysql database..so as far as I understand,It can't be null.

Comment: @nerd When you want to access order details again in view page you can pass the model to view in render array and in view you can access like echo $orders->order_date; and you render would be $this->render('checkout_shipping', array('orders'=>$orders),false,true);

Comment: Please see my previous comment I mentioned there. If you still in trouble you can send me controller function two models and structure of tables.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20866/discussion-between-ay34-and-nerd)

Comment: @nerd : I've edited your code which you gave me via email. Replace that and use. see my full edited answer. and code I've deleted previous and created new one.

Comment: @anup...Gud job Thanks....but still facing a issue..whenever i am using the url as YII defined: www.blablah.com/cart/checkout_shipping            then i am getting my shipping form filled already by the last address that i filled earlier.

Comment: Because you are using address in session you have find something else. I am not sure my logic says like this. and make sure you are not inserting values hard coded anywhere these should be dynamic.

Comment: Actually, I don't know your projects current scenario so I can't give suggestion. Tel me some flow so probably I could tel you. I been 2 days ago I think you could solve this.

Comment: The flow goes like this:
Login form--->>submitted--->>shipping form---->>submitted--->>payment form.
so basically if a user fills the shipping form,he has obviously selected an item.
For that only I want the Orders table to be populated along with the shipping_address table.

Comment: Then Don't use session id. POST shipping address id after it created. It's that much easy. But make sure you handle it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`insert into orders (orders_id) values (select max(orders_id)+1 from orders);`

Comment: Well thaks...but i know doing the mysql way...I want to implement in  YII controller

Comment: Sorry, your question was vague when I answered.  Your edits make it much better.